# Laravel, Jetstream with Inertia view returns a blank page

Tags: laravel, inertiajs, laravel-jetstream

I have used Laravel with Jetstream & Inertia to build a small backend solution, which works fine but when I try to move the views to a folder/dir it returns an empty page(blank page). I havent worked that much with laravel so I probably doing something dump.

Yes I run Npm run watch

**web.php**

```
Route::middleware(['auth:sanctum', 'verified'])->get('/upload/form', function () {
     return Inertia::render('Upload/Form');
})->name('upload.form');
```

**AppLayout.vue**

```
<jet-nav-link :href="route('upload.form')" :active="route().current('upload.form')">
   Upload form
</jet-nav-link>
```

**pages/Upload/Form.vue**

```
<template>
    <app-layout>
        <template #header>
            <h2 class="font-semibold text-xl text-gray-800 leading-tight">
                Upload Form
            </h2>
        </template>

        <div class="py-12">
            <div class="max-w-7xl mx-auto sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
                <div class="bg-white overflow-hidden shadow-xl sm:rounded-lg">
                    Hello form....
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </app-layout>
</template>
```

Comment: Assuming the vue file is indeed located at `Uploads/Form`; in `Inertia::render('Upload/Form')` you specifiy `Upload/Form`, then perhaps the missing 's' (Upload -> Uploads) causes the issue?

Comment: no its all upload so there's no S missing here

Comment: Ok. Then please update your question, because in your question you state the Vue file is located at `pages/Uploads/Form.vue` and according to your comment it actually is at `pages/Upload/Form.vue`.  Next thing to check would be: do you see any errors in your devtools of your web browser?

Comment: Updated. No I don't get any errors only a warning that the map.js cant befound

Comment: Thank you. Can you please elaborate on what you mean with: "..but when I try to move the views to a folder/dir..."? Which files are you trying to move? From and to which location?

Comment: Well creating a folder inside the views folder, same idea as the users folder. So views/ becomes views/upload/

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the code provided. Can you post your entire `Form.vue`? When I have seen blank pages as you're describing, it's often a minor syntax error in the vue's code ie. misspelled prop name etc.

Comment: I found the damm issue, as its javascript there was an issue with vue and not with laravel ....

Comment: @user759235 what was the issue ? i have same problem